# How I can access to oroPlatform API?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, orocommerce

I wanna access to OroPlatform API but unfortunately, I'm still getting message:

{"error":"no_encryption_key","error_description":"The encryption key does not exist.","message":"The encryption key does not exist."}

I have already create oauth_private.key and oauth_public.key in /var forlder. Currenlly in my dashboard I achieved delete the message of contact with the administrator for the key. But still I can request from Posman or another client.

I have tried with all these methods without success:

[https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/oauth/#:~:text=Authentication-,OAuth%20Authentication,-Authorization%20Code%20Grant](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/oauth/#:%7E:text=Authentication-,OAuth%20Authentication,-Authorization%20Code%20Grant)

I'm getting crazy with this issue. Somebody can help me please??

Comment: We've checked and it looks like OAuth2 authentication works as expected. For further investigation please provide us with more information:
 - What application do you use and what version?
 - Do you use either "OAuth Applications" or "Customer User OAuth Applications"?
 - What Grant Type do you use?
 - Do you use Postman build-in Auth functionality    or make request manually?
 - Is grant type of your OAuth app equal to    Postman parameter?
 - Is value of "Redirect URLs" equal (pay attention    to trailing slash) to "Callback URL" in Postman? (In case Authorization code grant type used)

Comment: Also, in case previous steps didn't help, please share the following information:
 - Body, headers, and log of requests you run;
 - Configuration of yours's oro_oauth2_server;
 - In case you use Postman build-in Auth functionality - parameters values of Auth section;
 - application's prod.log
 - output of "ls -l" inside of "~/var" directory or your application.

Here is an example of a plain token generation request: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKGZy.png